# Android: disable pinch zoom and pass event to Flash content

Tags: javascript, android, flash, zooming, pinch

I have a flash application written in actionscript 2.0 that shows vector architectural maps and works perfectly on common web browsers. There are many interactions with javascript functions called by user events on the webpage, such as zooming to a certain x,y point. This event is usually accomplished via the mouse wheel.

Now I have to make sure that the thing works on tablet pc, in particular the Galaxy Tab. The first thing I have to fix is that, obviously, there is no mouse wheel and the user naturally tries to pinch zoom the flash application, with the result of zooming the entire web browser.

What I need is to listen to the multitouch gesture and, when a pinch zoom event is called, disable the default zooming event and call a javascript/flash function that allows my flash app to zoom only the objects that need to be zoomed: in few words, the browser stays still and only a part of the flash zooms in or out.

Consider that I am totally new to Android and that I already have working javascript functions to call flash object functions for the zooming purpose, so I just need to connect them to some android things that tell me when the user tries to pinch zoom in and when he tries to pinch zoom out (and possibly the x,y point of zoom).

Thanks a lot for your help!
Max (Italy)

Comment: If you disable the native browser zoom in your hosted page does it get you closer to what you want to see? http://garrows.com/?p=337

Answer (score 0):

Passing a JavaScript call from android to flash is a very very hard task as far as I know.

Not because of android (follow this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/JavascriptBridge to pass a JavaScript call to a web page  ), but because of flash securities for local content.

It is not too much of an issue on a local computer, but the flashplayer on android is very very buggy.

I think the best is to try to find an other solution if possible...